# Syntax for MailApp.sendEmail google App sheets and correct place in function?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, gmail

I've created a system that uses a google form to enter information on a spreadsheet. At the moment the form is submitted, I would like to send an email to the relevant approver.

I'm having trouble parsing the eventObject.email value to the 'to field in the MailApp.sendEmail function.

```
   MailApp.sendEmail({
   to: eventObject.email,
   subject: "A new request has been submitted",
   htmlBody: "Please review at the following link: arbritrary link"
      });
```

If I define the email address as a string it will send, but when it is eventObject.email I get no email and the error "Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient"

The code is as follows:

```
    //Load the Moment.js library once.
var moment = Moment.load();

var GLOBAL = {
  //the id of the form we will use to create calendar events 
  formId : "arbritrary form ID",  
  
  //the id of the calendar we will create events on
  calendarId : "arbritrary calendar ID",
  
  //a mapping of form item titles to sections of the calendar event
  formMap : {
    eventTitle: "Person Name and Organisation",
    startTime : "Start Date / Time",
    endTime: "End Date / Time",
    description: "Description of work / Additional Notes",
    location: "Location of Work and/or Room ID",
    email: "Approver Email Address",
    
  },
}

function onFormSubmit() {
  var eventObject = getFormResponse();
  var event = createCalendarEvent(eventObject);
}

function getFormResponse() {
  // Get a form object by opening the form using the
  // form id stored in the GLOBAL variable object
  var form = FormApp.openById(GLOBAL.formId),
      //Get all responses from the form. 
      //This method returns an array of form responses
      responses = form.getResponses(),
      //find the length of the responses array
      length = responses.length,
      //find the index of the most recent form response
      //since arrays are zero indexed, the last response 
      //is the total number of responses minus one
      lastResponse = responses[length-1],
      //get an array of responses to every question item 
      //within the form for which the respondent provided an answer
      itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses(),
      //create an empty object to store data from the last 
      //form response
      //that will be used to create a calendar event
      eventObject = {};
  //Loop through each item response in the item response array
  for (var i = 0, x = itemResponses.length; i<x; i++) {
    //Get the title of the form item being iterated on
    var thisItem = itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle(),
        //get the submitted response to the form item being
        //iterated on
        thisResponse = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
    //based on the form question title, map the response of the 
    //item being iterated on into our eventObject variable
    //use the GLOBAL variable formMap sub object to match 
    //form question titles to property keys in the event object
    switch (thisItem) {
      case GLOBAL.formMap.eventTitle:
        eventObject.title = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.startTime:
        eventObject.startTime = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.endTime:
        eventObject.endTime = thisResponse;
        break; 
      case GLOBAL.formMap.description:
        eventObject.description = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.location:
        eventObject.location = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.email:
        eventObject.email = thisResponse;
        break;
        
   
      }
   
    
  return eventObject;
   
   MailApp.sendEmail({
   to: eventObject.email,
   subject: "A new request has been submitted",
   htmlBody: "Please review at the following link: arbritrary link"
      });
 }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### `thisItem` is the question, not the response

- `GLOBAL.formMap.email` is the value of the specified key, so `"Approver Email Address"`
- Thus, `switch (thisItem) ... case GLOBAL.formMap.email` will never be fullfilled.

**Solution:**

Modify

`switch (thisItem)`

to
`switch (thisResponse)`

In this case the email will be set correctly if the form submit value is "Approver Email Address".